# Objective C Action doesn't perform unless I value in PickerView will be changed

Tags: objective-c

I am working on app with two view controllers. On the first one is one textfield for input1 along with label for end result. On second view I have textfield for input2, and one PickerView for currenct values. Main features are:

- On first run user has to go to 2nd ViewController and set desired values in Input2 txtfield and on UIPicker. They are stored by NSUserDefault function - note that storing data works charmly.
- On 1st ViewController User has to type Integer in txtfield and after that it should show the result on label below - (input1*input2)+UIPickerValue

What my main problem is: after typing values into input1 txtfield it should calculate insantly (because of calculate method in viewWillAppear) but it doesn't. To obtain a result I have to switch to second view and choose value on UIPicker. Without that, result is "0.00 (null)". Do you have any ideas where did I go wrong? I have no clue about that. F.Y.I. there's is another class Settings, only with properties in its header.

```
ViewController.m

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   self.energyTextField.delegate = self;
  [self calculateThePrice];



}

 -(void)userDidSetSettings:(Settings *)currentSettings{
    self.currentSettings = currentSettings;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void){


    [self calculateThePrice];




    }];
}
```

(...)

```
# pragma mark Calculating and Segues Implementations

-(void)calculateThePrice

{
    float wynik = self.currentSettings.kwh * self.currentSettings.price;
    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f %@", wynik , self.currentSettings.currency];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingSegue"]){
        self.currentSettings = [[Settings alloc]init];
        self.currentSettings.kwh = (int)[self.energyTextField.text integerValue];


        SettingsVC *settingsVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        settingsVC.currentSettings = self.currentSettings;
        settingsVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

SettingsVC.m

```
#import "SettingsVC.h"


@interface SettingsVC () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation SettingsVC

#pragma mark - UserDefaults Implementation

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self createCurrencyArray];


    NSUserDefaults *priceDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *priceDefText = [priceDef stringForKey:@"priceCall"];

    _priceTextField.text = priceDefText;   

    NSUserDefaults *currencyDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [_currencyPicker selectRow:[currencyDef integerForKey:@"currencyCall"]
         inComponent:0 animated:NO];

}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {


    NSString *textOfPriceTexField = _priceTextField.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textOfPriceTexField forKey:@"priceCall"];

}
```

(...)

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

    [self userDidFinishSetting];

}

-(void)userDidFinishSetting{
    [self.delegate userDidSetSettings:self.currentSettings];
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{



    NSInteger selectedRow = [_currencyPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"currencyCall"];


    self.currentSettings.currency = [self.currencyArray objectAtIndex:row];
    self.currentSettings.price = [self.priceTextField.text floatValue];

    //[self userDidFinishSetting];

}
```

EDIT #2

I changed method to

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    self.energyTextField.delegate = self;
    [self calculateThePrice];
}
```

It is one step closer, but value still won't calculate unless PickerValue is changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `-viewWillAppear:` method is part of a family of "transition" methods that let the view controller know when its view (the object referenced by the view controller's `view` property) is added or removed from the view hierarchy (this is different from being drawn, by the way). So when you do input the text, the method has already run a long time ago.

To get the desired effect, you need the methods in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. If you just want to act upon the text field's losing focus, `-textFieldDidEndEditing:` should suffice. Don't forget to set the text field's `delegate` property to the object that implements the method.

ETA: It looks like your `currentSettings` object only gets allocated when you perform the segue. If you try to use it before that, the "magic" of Objective C will yield a bunch of zeroes for calling methods on a nil object. Also make sure your `Settings` class reads from NSUserDefaults and initialises its properties to sensible values in case the information isn't there.

Comment: When I am adding protocol above the xCode says that "Duplicate definition will be ignored", I am confused where I should put this.

Comment: I don't see what could be causing Xcode to complain. You don't need to make `SettingsVC` implement the protocol but that's not the cause for the warning.